An equilateral triangle is partitioned into smaller equilateral triangular pieces. Prove that two of the pieces are the same size.
Here's the Problem (Its an NZMO $2019$ question):

An equilateral triangle is partitioned into smaller equilateral triangular pieces. Prove that
two of the pieces are the same size.

As well as being a pretty weird Olympiad question to grasp the meaning of, I also do not know how to finish this question.
Here is my beginning:
Based on the information on the question, we can logically state that there are only $3$ types of vertex for the equilateral triangle.

$•$ Type $A:$ incident with only $2$ edges at $60°$.


$•$ Type $B :$ incident with exactly $4$ edges at angles $60°, 60, 60°, 180°$


$•$ Type $C :$ incident with exactly $6$ edges forming $6$, $60°$ angles.

There can be no other types of vertex, because all the angles must be $60°$ or $180°$ or $300°$
in the corners of the original large triangle.
I have only so far been able to solve this question up to here. If anybody could help me to finish this question, I would appreciate it. Thank you very much.
Edit: I would like the proof to be different from the one Beni Bogosel suggested for another similar question (it is on Math Stack Exchange too): Dissecting an equilateral triangle into equilateral triangles of pairwise different sizes
Beni suggests that proceeding in a recursive way:
"The triangle $A_1B_1C_1$ and find one smallest triangle pointing downwards with side contained in $B_1C_1$ $...$ this triangle has two neighbor triangles and one of them is smaller, which we denote by $A_2B_2C_2$, and so on $...$ continue this procedure indefinitely because all the triangle sides are different."
This is the last question (Q$5$ of an invitational paper) and they began it in my way above. I would like some to continue with this solution (obviously not their approach as I don't really understand it). Thanks.

Make a cut parallel to the base (of any size). The remaining trapezium can then be cut into equilateral triangles. The two on the corners must have the same size.

@RedFive Unless there are multiple small triangles along each leg of the trapezium.

Even then there would be two of the same size in order to completely tile the trapezium. Proving it of course is quite a different matter.

It was Q5 on the Round 2 paper, so they were not expecting a simple solution...

@peterwhy I have edited it. Does this help? Thanks.

@RedFive Indeed, also the one on the duplicate question seems a little too simple for a solution.
